# Python: Concat two dataframe with number of times row repeats

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Have got two dataframe like below with index values:
***tab_df***

```
        row     table_no    table_bit   
83      45          1           1
84      45          1           2
85      45          1           3
86      45          2           1
87      45          2           2
88      45          2           3
91      46          1           1
92      46          1           2
93      46          1           3
```

***item_df***

```
        count   Item
15      2       Apple
16      2       Apple
17      1       Lemon
18      2       Apricot
19      2       Apricot
35      2       Melon
36      2       Melon
37      1       Orange
38      1       Potato
```

Condition to be considered:

1. `tab_df` rows along with index value should not be jumbled. It's fixed.
2. `item_df` rows to be concat/joined with `tab_df` to attain `output_df` considering below rules:
   (`item_df` data will be in row-table_no-table_bit order. Each row can have any number of table_no. Each table_no will have only 3 table_bit.)
   2.1. `item_df` rows  to be arranged/joined in the same order with `tab_df` the number of times it repeats. [Column count gives number of times that particular Item repeats]. E.g., Item Apple repeats twice so it takes two bits from first row, then comes Lemon which takes single bit from same row and continues.
   2.2. No Item should share `table_bit` across rows. E.g., On arranging up items with rule 2.1, at the end of *row 45*, after *Apricot, Melon* need to be arranged but that row got only single *table_bit* left out. So, need to check for next Item which needs only single bit and that to be arranged there and Melon should be moved to other row and carry on with the same flow as of rule 2.1
   2.3. Each Item in `item_df` got it's respective index which should not be changed. If any item is rearranged like Melon same index need to be carried out for every item.

***output_df***

```
tab_index    row     table_no    table_bit   item_index  count   Item
83           45          1           1           15         2    Apple
84           45          1           2           16         2    Apple
85           45          1           3           17         1    Lemon
86           45          2           1           18         2    Apricot
87           45          2           2           19         2    Apricot
88           45          2           3           37         1    Orange
91           46          1           1           35         2    Melon
92           46          1           2           36         2    Melon
93           46          1           3           38         1    Potato
```

Looking forward. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: can u simply the question and give example output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like there ought to be an easier way to do this, but if I understand you correctly, the following should work.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'row': {83: 45, 84: 45, 85: 45, 86: 45, 87: 45, 88: 45, 91: 46, 92: 46, 93: 46}, 
        'table_no': {83: 1, 84: 1, 85: 1, 86: 2, 87: 2, 88: 2, 91: 1, 92: 1, 93: 1}, 
        'table_bit': {83: 1, 84: 2, 85: 3, 86: 1, 87: 2, 88: 3, 91: 1, 92: 2, 93: 3}}
tab_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'count': {15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 1, 18: 2, 19: 2, 35: 2, 36: 2, 37: 1, 38: 1}, 
         'Item': {15: 'Apple', 16: 'Apple', 17: 'Lemon', 18: 'Apricot', 19: 'Apricot', 35: 'Melon', 36: 'Melon', 37: 'Orange', 38: 'Potato'}}
item_df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**Code**

```
tmp = item_df.reset_index().groupby('Item', as_index=False).agg(
    {'index': list, 'count': 'first'})

tmp = tmp.loc[tmp.groupby('count').cumcount().sort_values().index].explode('index')

tmp = tmp.loc[:, ['index','count','Item']].rename(columns={'index':'item_index'})
tab_df[tmp.columns] = tmp.to_numpy()

print(tab_df)

    row  table_no  table_bit item_index count     Item
83   45         1          1         15     2    Apple
84   45         1          2         16     2    Apple
85   45         1          3         17     1    Lemon
86   45         2          1         18     2  Apricot
87   45         2          2         19     2  Apricot
88   45         2          3         37     1   Orange
91   46         1          1         35     2    Melon
92   46         1          2         36     2    Melon
93   46         1          3         38     1   Potato
```

**Explanation**

- First, use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Item`. Use [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to turn `index` values (now a column) per group into lists (e.g. for `Apple`: `[15, 16]`), and for column `count` simply get [`.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) (e.g. for `Apple`: `2`).
- In the next step, apply `df.groupby` again, this time on `count` (now: `[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]` associated with `['Apple', 'Apricot', 'Lemon', 'Melon', 'Orange', 'Potato']`), and get [`.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). Sorting these values using [`Series.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) gets us a rearranged index `[0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5]`. We want the original index order adjusted in this way, which we can achieve by nesting the above inside [`tmp.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Chain [`.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on column `index` to get the lists back as rows again.
- The row order for `tmp` (derived from `item_df`) is now correct; last step is just cosmetic: i.e. getting the columns in the desired order as well: `tmp = tmp.loc[:, ['index','count','Item']]`, and chaining [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to change col name `index` into `item_index`.
- Finally, add these columns to `tab_df`. Use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html), since we want to ignore the index of `tmp`.